# multi insert one form

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have this code with two tables
Table data and auto table
1 are connected to many with the id of personal data, that is, an owner a lot of cars.
Now when I insert all the data fits the personal dates and a single car.

```
<?php
include 'con.php';
if(isset($_POST['Submit1'])){
$date_str = $_POST['data'];
$converted = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_str));
$cognome=addslashes($_REQUEST['cognome']);
$nome=addslashes($_REQUEST['nome']);
$data_nascita=addslashes($_REQUEST['data_nascita']);
$luogo_nascita=addslashes($_REQUEST['luogo_nascita']);
$ruolo=addslashes($_REQUEST['ruolo']);
$auto=addslashes($_REQUEST['auto']);
$fabbrica=addslashes($_REQUEST['fabbrica']);
$modello=addslashes($_REQUEST['modello']);
$matricola=addslashes($_REQUEST['matricola']);
$stato=addslashes($_REQUEST['stato']);
$auto1=addslashes($_REQUEST['arma1']);
$fabbrica1=addslashes($_REQUEST['fabbrica1']);
$modello1=addslashes($_REQUEST['modello1']);
$matricola1=addslashes($_REQUEST['matricola1']);
$stato1=addslashes($_REQUEST['stato1']);
$rand = rand ();
$a=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO dati_personali (data, cognome, nome, data_nascita, luogo_nascita, ruolo, codice)
VALUES ('$converted','$cognome', '$nome', '".$_REQUEST['data_nascita']."', '$luogo_nascita', '$ruolo','$rand')");
$b=   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO auto (id, auto, fabbrica, modello, matricola, stato)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$auto."', '".$fabbrica."', '".$modello."', ' ".$matricola."', '".$stato."'),('".$auto1."', '".$fabbrica1."', '".$modello1."', '".$matricola1."', '".$stato1."')");
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but if I change the query so

```
$b=   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO auto (id, auto, fabbrica, modello, targa, stato)  
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$auto."', '".$fabbrica."', '".$modello."', '".$targa."','".$stato."'),  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$auto."', '".$fabbrica."', '".$modello."', '".$targa."','".$stato."')");}
```

the system inserts two. but only the last.
How can I do??

Comment: Please paste your code in with proper formatting. Your question is impossible to undertand the way you've posted it.

Comment: @ArshSingh English is the language of SO.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help with formatting your post.

Comment: @Barmar , i know very well about that , if the op is from italy and i'm too , and he is not able to make an question which you guys can understand , i better ask him in italian and better later inside my answer type in english.

Comment: He's been here for 3 years, he should know how to format by now.

Comment: @Barmar Formatting question , and typing in english , is different thing. he seems not to be a frequent english speaker. just matter of understanding the question , and get into the problem , you can't ask someone forcefully to speak in english , if he is not able to do so . So better we be bit flexible and try to understand in better way.

Comment: I know, I was making an unrelated comment.

Comment: @Barmar and i bet that he didn't even understand what you were saying to him , as seems like the english is translated from google translate , my only motive to speak different language , which op understands , is concern of making op understand , that were not able to understand what he said.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This is solved, I modified the query:

```
$a=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO dati_personali (data, cognome, nome, data_nascita, luogo_nascita, ruolo, codice)
VALUES ('$converted','$cognome', '$nome', '".$_REQUEST['data_nascita']."', '$luogo_nascita', '$ruolo','$rand')");
$a .=   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO auto (id, auto, fabbrica, modello, targa, stato)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$auto."', '".$fabbrica."', '".$modello."', '".$targa."', '".$stato."')");
$a .=   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO auto (id, auto, fabbrica, modello, targa, stato)
VALUES ((select MAX(id) FROM dati_personali), '".$auto1."', '".$fabbrica1."', '".$modello1."', '".$targa1."', '".$stato1."')");
```